Transformation of Lagrangian to Eulerian velocity
I am trying to understand the example on page 34 of this essay where a transformation of Lagrangian velocity to Eulerian velocity is shown.
The (one-dimensional) trajectories of the parcels are provided at pag.18 eq.(6) as 
$\tilde{x}(a,t)=U_0 t + a (1+2 t)^{1/2}$ 
where a is the position of the parcel at t=0
Consequently the lagrangian velocities are: 
$\tilde{u}(a,t)=\dfrac{\partial{\tilde{x}}}{\partial t}=U_0 + a (1+2 t)^{-1/2}$                           (eq.(7) pag.18) 
The Eularian velocity at x at time t is the velocity of the fluid parcel which is at $\tilde{x}$ at time t (i.e. $\tilde{x}(a,t)=x$).
Then, the eq(6) should be inverted:
$a(\tilde{x},t)=\dfrac{\tilde{x}-U_0 t}{(1+2 t)^{1/2}}$ 
(first equation on pag.34 where, I suppose, there is a typo in the exponent of denominator)
(I quote the text of the essay on page 34)
"Now eliminate a from $\tilde{u}$ of Eq. (7) in favor of the position, $\tilde{x}$"
So far everything seems clear.
What I don't understand is the result reported in the essay:
$\tilde{u}(a(\tilde{x},t),t)=U_0+\tilde{x} (1+2 t)^{-1}$ 
If you simply replaced a in eq.(7) with the expression found above for a, the result would be different.
Then, the questions are:
what is the process that leads to the last equation?
what is its logic?
Perhaps a hint is in the following essay sentence:
This procedure amounts to forming a composite function from the
Lagrangian trajectory and velocity. Notice that the
spatially-uniform velocity, $U_0$, carries over directly.
